# HTTP Post request get cancelled after 2 minutes and process is working

Tags: apache, http, browser, httpresponse, execution

My problem is:

**HTTP request gets cancelled after 2 minutes but server side processing still continues.**

I have large data processing and my database contains huge data.So i am using a normal form submit method for a processing screen and when i checked the browser console the request status becomes cancelled.But on the server the process is continuing after this request cancelling.Also when the request is cancelled a file wil be downloaded automatically which cannot be opened,also the file extension is not there.I have made the maximum execution time limit to unlimited using

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

,but it didnt changed the situation.In my code i have writted some code to write contents into a file.So after the request gets cancelled the file writing operation continues.I am trying to resolve this error but didnt find any solution.Please help me.
I am using apache server.

Screenshots
[image: Status of request]
[image: Header details]
Process i am doing:

```
 1.Selecting large number of data from a table which contains large number of data.
 2.Checks whether each record matches certian conditions
 3.Matching records are written into a file and that file is report generation
 4.Allowing the user to download the file after the process completion.
```

I have heared that if the client did'nt recive any response after a particular time then it will cancel the request to the server.Is this the issue with me.If so how can i resolve it.?

Comment: You need to give some more information about what you'r posting, and what your server is doing.

Comment: I have updated the question. plz check and those who are downvotting please let me know the reason too so that i can improve the question.

Answer (score 0):

Php doesn't find out the request is cancelled until it tries to send data to client. You should be able to resolve this by doing this at regular intervals:

```
echo '    '; flush();
```

This will end your script if ignore_user_abort is false.